# Installing jnius using pip

Tags: python, android, visual-studio, visual-c++, kivy

I installed Kivy successfully. But got error when run a program which is the module "Jnius" is not found.

For Jnius, I installed Cython, jdk, jre and add the path variables. Then got error to install the visual studio for C++.

While installing the Visual studio, the installing window get closed automatically. Then, I choose another option to install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7. Installation is successfull.

But again got error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Embdedded the images in the question, removed links

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something like something like that today when i tried to install a package in pip command and the when i tried to install it binary it worked:

```
pip install --only-binary :all: jnius
```

you can try this and see if it's any help